# import a timestamp from a .txt file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am currently trying to import a .txt file using numpy's genfromtxt function.  Typically this works great.  However, this time I am importing a heat vs time txt file, where the time is recorded in a 00:00:00 format.  So at the 10 second mark, the time column would read 00:00:10.  At the one hour mark, the time column would read 01:00:00, and so on.  Unfortunately, numpy's genfromtxt function reads this as "nan".  Any advice on how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

Heat_up_time = np.genfromtxt('Lucifer Heat Treating Oven Heat Up Time(1).txt')
time = Heat_up_time[:,][:,1]
temp_f = Heat_up_time[:,][:,2]

print(time)
print(temp_f)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.  There may be an easier way, but what I found was to go into the txt file and remove all of the colons.  This makes one minute look like "100" and on hour look like "10000".

I used the following code to "fix" the time stamps into our 60 second minute and 60 minute hour world.  There is probably an easier way, and the more experienced coders will probably laugh at the clunkiness and bulkiness of my code, but it worked.

```
def fix_time(array):
    result = []
    j = 10
    k = 20
    l = 1
    y = 1
    p = 0
    for i in array:
        n = i
        if i < 100:
            result.append(i)
        elif n/j < k and i < 10000:
            i = i-l*40 - p * 40
            result.append(i)
        elif n/j < k and i >= 10000:
            i = i - y * 40 - p * 40
            result.append(i)
        else:
            k = k + 10
            l = l + 1
            if l == 60:
                y = 160
                k = 1010
            if n/j <= k and k < 1010:
                i = i - l * 40 - p * 40
                result.append(i)
            elif n/j <= k and k >= 1010 and k < 1020:
                i = i - y * 40 - p * 40
                result.append(i)
            elif n/j <= k and k >= 1020:
                p = p + 1
                i = i - y * 40 - p * 40
                result.append(i)
            elif p > 1:
                k = k + 400
                y = y + 160
                p = 0
                if n/j <= k:
                    i = i - y * 40 - p * 40
                    result.append(i)
            else:
                while n/j >= k:
                    k = k + 10
                    p = p + 1
                if n/j < k:
                    p = p + 1
                    i = i - y * 40 - p * 40
                    result.append(i)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `Pandas` to import the file? `Pandas` is usually pretty good when your data is well structured.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Lucifer Heat Treating Oven Heat Up Time(1).txt')
```

Comment: no, this didn't work.  It didn't separate the columns, just read the data in as a 1D array when it should have been a 3D array.  I tried using the delimiter command, but it didn't work.